# How to create a button that can be used with embed code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working on a project where I need to create an embeddable button. I just want to give some code to the clients and ask them to put it where they want the button to appear on their websites. What is the best approach to it? As an example please see the following image:

[image: From OpenCal]

I will be really thankful if someone can provide some example code.

Comment: And what do you expect this button to do? You need to provide far more details about what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Well, why don't you give them the same code you used to show the button? ...

Comment: sorry...I want this button to just redirect to a page for registration and login for that respective client i.e the client's customers will click on that button to be redirected to the login, registration page in our system for that client. I hope that clears things up.

Comment: If so then make it a simple link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest form would be to provide a hyperlink:

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/dosomething" title="DoSomething">Do Something</a>
```

Or you could use an image button:

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/dosomething" title="DoSomething">
    <img src="http://mysite.com/images/a.jpg" alt="DoSomething" />
</a>
```

These both remove dependencies on CSS and JS.

Or you can do it like suggested in your question:

```
<script src="http://mysite.com/scripts/embedbutton.js">
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysite.com/css/embedbutton.css" />');
    document.write('<div id="mybutton" onclick="DoSomething(event);">DoSomething</div>');

    function DoSomething()
    {
        /* action code here */
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that the javascript solution is the one thtat you need.
Create an javascript that will write the HTML of your button. Put the code in public/js/mybutton.js for example.

```
var link = 'http://yoursite.com';
var text = '<div><a href="' + link + '"><img src="' 
    + link 
    + '/public/images/image.png" alt="Some alt text for the image" /></a></div>';
document.write(text);
```

Then provide a script tag in your page for the users to embed your butscriptton.

```
<script src="http://yoursite.com/public/js/mybutton.js"></script>
```

The result will be a image with link to your site, rendered right after the script. You can use inline styling also.
I belive that this is good option when you want prevent your button styling modifications.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple link:

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com">Blah</a>
```

and then ask your clients to embed this code into their sites. Obviously depending on the information you need to exchange between the client site and your site there could be additional parameters, javascript code, ...

Comment: But I also want to have the button styled. Will it be ok if I pass in the style properties in the style tag of the button as well?

Comment: You could make it an image button or something using the `<img>` tag and pointing to an image on your site.